# Sorttable.js (Javascript table sorting) not working when table created in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, sorttable.js

I'm trying to use the [sorttable.js](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/) package to make an HTML table sortable when the column header is clicked.  I can get this to work just fine when the table is declared statically in the HTML:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/48558kLd/)

```
<table class="sortable" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Points</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Joe</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Abraham</td>
    <td>Jones</td> 
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

However, when I create the table with javascript, the sorting functionality isn't there anymore, and I get error messages on the console:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/48558kLd/1/)

```
  tbl_array = new Array()
  tbl_array = [["Firstname","Lastname","Points"], ["Eve","Jackson","94"], ["Joe","Smith","50"], ["Abraham","Jones","4"]]
  var body = document.body,
        tbl = document.getElementById('summaryTable');

    // clear all rows on the table
    while(tbl.rows.length > 0){
        tbl.deleteRow(0)
    }
    tbl.style.width  = '100px';
    tbl.style.border = '1px solid black';

    numRows = tbl_array.length
    numCols = tbl_array[0].length

    // insert each 2D array entry into a table cell
    for(var i = 0; i < numRows; i++){

    // insert header
    if (i == 0){
        var header = tbl.createTBody();
        var row = header.insertRow();
            for (var j=0; j < numCols; ++j){
            var cell = document.createElement('th')
            cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(tbl_array[i][j]));
            cell.style.border='1px solid black';
            cell.style.fontWeight = "bold";
            row.appendChild(cell)
          }
    }

    else{
      var tr = tbl.insertRow();
      for(var j = 0; j < numCols; j++){
          var td = tr.insertCell();
          td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(tbl_array[i][j]));
          td.style.border = '1px solid black';
      }
    }
    }
  console.log("tbl", tbl)
```

The only thing I can think of is that I'm not formatting the table correctly with the javascript, but when I printed both tables to the console and examined their structures, they were basically the same:

```
<table ...>
    <tbody>
        <tr ...>
            <th>..</th>
            <th>..</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>..</td>
            <td>..</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Is my error in the way I'm creating the table with javascript? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The first has a `thead` and `tbody` while the second only has a `tbody`  Also, consider how the table gets sorted - there's some js only that runs and looks for class=sortable and makes it a sortable table.   As your code runs after that, you need to run the same initialise.

Comment: In addition to the answer by @SteamDev, a newer script would be required (as I found out) available [here](https://github.com/stuartlangridge/sorttable/blob/master/sorttable/sorttable.js).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sorttable.js` assumes all tables are already in the HTML when it initializes; your table is dynamically generated, so you have to bootstrap the `makeSortable` method manually.

Right before your `console.log`, try inserting this:

```
sorttable.makeSortable(document.getElementById('summaryTable'));
```